# How can I display Gravtar using Middleman?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, middleman, gravatar

I'm attempting to build my first ruby gem that uses [Middleman Frontmatter](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/frontmatter/) to display Gravatar images.

My goal is to use frontmatter like this as an *input*:

```
---
email: example@mail.com
---
```

...and *output* the associated Gravatar image in a .erb file like this:

```
<%= gravatar_for(article.data.email) %>
```

Here is what I have come up with based on the instructions provided by Gravatar for displaying images via ruby:

```
require "gravatar/version"
require 'digest/md5'

module Gravatar

  def gravatar_for(email)
    hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email.chomp.downcase)
    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
  end

end
```

The error I receive when the code is run is

```
NoMethodError at/
undefined method `gravatar_for'...
```

The gem and repo can be found here: https://rubygems.org/gems/snagagrav

Comment: You should explain what issue you are having, maybe add some code?

Comment: @rainkinz Sorry. First time poster -- hit submit too soon.

Comment: no worries, done that myself :-)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this doesn't involve making your own Middleman extension:

Just put this in `config.rb`:

```
require 'digest/md5'
helpers do
  def gravatar_for(email)
    hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email.chomp.downcase)
    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
  end
end
```

And now in templates you can do:

```
<%= gravatar_for(article.data.email) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've successfully tried adding something like this to your config.rb:

```
require 'digest/md5'
class Gravatar < Middleman::Extension
  def initialize(app, options_hash={}, &block)
    super
    puts "#{options_hash.inspect}"
  end

  helpers do
    def make_a_link(url, text)
      "<a href='#{url}'>#{text}</a>"
    end

    def gravatar_for(email)
      hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email.chomp.downcase)
      "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
    end
  end
end

::Middleman::Extensions.register(:gravatar, Gravatar)

set :css_dir, 'stylesheets'

set :js_dir, 'javascripts'

set :images_dir, 'images'

# Build-specific configuration
configure :build do
  activate :gravatar
end
```

Then in your template:

```
---
title: Welcome to Middleman
email: example@mail.com
---

<div class="welcome">
  <h1>Middleman is Watching</h1>
  <p class="doc">
    <%= gravatar_for(current_page.data.email) %>
  </p><!-- .doc -->
</div><!-- .welcome -->
```

That works for me. Seems like you need to turn your gem into a MiddleMan extension and register it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Here is what I did:

Created a gem called `middleman-gravatar.rb` in directory `middleman-gravatar/lib/`

```
class MiddlemanGravatar < ::Middleman::Extension

  helpers do
    def gravatar_for(email, options_hash={})
      if email
        # Creates md5 hash for email address
        hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email.chomp.downcase)
        # Returns Gravatar image for email (.jpg)
        "<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}.jpg' />"
      else
        # Returns default mysterman image if no Gravatar exists
        "<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/?d=mm' />"
      end
    end
  end

end

::Middleman::Extensions.register(:middleman_gravatar, MiddlemanGravatar)
```

added this to the `config.rb` file

```
# Gravatar
require('middleman-gravatar/lib/middleman-gravatar')
activate :middleman_gravatar
```

added this to the `index.html.erb` to show the Gravatar

```
<%= gravatar_for(article.data.gravatar) %>
```

and added this to the frontmatter of the article file

```
---
gravatar: email@example.com
---
```